Alternatives to ChatGPT for programming in R
I would like to know if anyone knows (and recommends) a free AI with better results than ChatGPT for programming in R (statistical analysis and data visualization). Until now it was working well, but lately it's been very slow (at least for me). Thank you so much.

What would you like the AI to do?
